# Android Spinner selection /sometimes/ not showing or detectable

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner

There are numerous questions on SO about spinner/drop-down selections not displaying, but this problem is a bit different as it is very intermittent.

The spinner in question work perfectly, and changing the spinner selection triggers various things in my app. However, every so often the spinner is blank when it is not dropped down.

Clicking the blank space drops down the selection panel and all options are present as expected, but when an option is selected the spinner remains blank and the actions that should follow a selection do not happen.

I have uploaded a video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yc-5wRY-QfWZx0MS0flZn9_LcIdzzAvm/view?usp=sharing) that shows the problem.

(In the video every time the drop down list disappears it is because I have tapped on an option. For some reson my screen recorded did not shows the clicks. When I select an option, one of the resulting actions shoudl be that the button at the top of the screen should change to show the selected region's Amazon URL - this is hoe you can see that the `setOnItemSelectedListener` is not firing either.)

There doesn't seem to be any real pattern to when the spinner appears blank. It has happened:

- when opening the app afresh after a long time (so cold app start effectively)
- when returning to the activity from another activity
- when returning to the app from another app or the home screen

BUT it only happens very infrequently.

If it only happened when returning to the activity then (the second and third cases above) then I would suspect that I was failing to do something in `onResume()`, but it also happens sometimes when the app is started fresh.

As you can see in the video, rotating the screen restores the correct functionality. As does exiting the app and swiping it from the running apps, then restarting.

I have tried various solutions to similar problems posted on here, but none have made any difference. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530584/why-does-an-spinner-disappear-and-reappear-again-on-touch) and its answers seemed most likley to help. Sadly not.

The spinner is defined in the layout as follows:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spin_aff_id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

And it is populated with options as follows:

```
private void _populate_ids_spinner() {

    amalfi.get_affids_fromprefs(affiliateRegions);
    amalfi.affiliate_ids_string.clear();
    amalfi.regions_present_in_affid_spinner.clear();

    Object assoc_id_for_region;
    Object spinner_text_for_region;

    for (String region : affiliateRegions.regionIds) {
        assoc_id_for_region = amalfi.assoc_ids.get(region);
        spinner_text_for_region = amalfi.spinner_text.get(region);
        if (assoc_id_for_region != null && spinner_text_for_region != null && assoc_id_for_region.toString().length() > 0) {
            amalfi.affiliate_ids_string.add(spinner_text_for_region.toString());
            amalfi.regions_present_in_affid_spinner.add(region);
        }
    }

    // viewBinding.spinAffId.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, amalfi.affiliate_ids_string));
    idsSpinnerArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, amalfi.affiliate_ids_string);
    viewBinding.spinAffId.setAdapter(idsSpinnerArrayAdapter);
    idsSpinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

With `_populate_ids_spinner()` being called in both `onStart()` and `onResume()`.

As I say, the important thing here seems to be that the spinner works perfectly 99% of the time, but when it gets into the invisible state it take either an orientation change or app restart to correct it (I need to experiment more, but I **don't** think starting a new activity and returning to the main activity where this spinner lives fixes it).